# Why isnt python nmap scanner working with dpy?

Tags: python, discord.py, nmap

I have been trying to make a nmap scanner and put it in a discord bot.
However it doesnt seem to work. It isnt even throwing any error or anything

Can someone please tell me how should I get it to work

````
@client.command()
async def nmap(ctx, *, arg = "None"):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if arg == "None":
        embed = discord.Embed(color=000000, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name="Occult AutoBot Revamped")
        embed.add_field(name='No ip',value="Enter an IP to scan", inline=True)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after = 10)
    else:
        nmScan = nmap.PortScanner()
        embed = discord.Embed(color=000000, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
        embed.set_author(name="Occult AutoBot Revamped")
        embed.add_field(name='Starting NMAP scanner',value=f"Ip --> {arg}", inline=True)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after = 20)
        try:
            print("here")
            nmScan.scan(arg, '1-65535')
            embed = discord.Embed(color=000000, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
            embed.set_author(name="Occult AutoBot Revamped")
            embed.add_field(name='Host Name',value=f"{nmScan[arg].hostname()}", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name='State',value=f"{nmScan[arg].state()}", inline=True)
            tcp_ports = nmScan[arg]['tcp'].keys()
            for i in tcp_ports:
                embed.add_field(name='Open TCP Port',value=str(i), inline=True)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after = 20)  
        except:
            embed = discord.Embed(color=000000, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
            embed.set_author(name="Occult AutoBot Revamped")
            embed.add_field(name='Invalid IP',value="The IP is invalid", inline=True)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after = 10)```
````

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with Discord, so please trim down your example to a minimal piece of code that reproduces the problem. Also include what package and version `nmap` refers to.

Comment: What exactly is ```nmap```? Could you explain about it briefly in the question?

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who find this question in the future , I managed to find a fix for the issue

The issue - The NMAP software wasnt in my PATH (the path variable)

Putting it their solved the problem

And also as Thomas stated , THIS ISSUE HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH DISCORD OR DISCORD.PY

Hope this helps :)